# macOS - how to add com.apple.developer.driverkit entitlement to team provisioning profile

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, macos-catalina, entitlements

I am trying to set up a new project to replace a KEXT with DEXT for Catalina.

Xcode is asking complaining that the team provisioning profile doesn't include the com.apple.developer.driverkit entitlement.

I can't find the correct procedure to get that entitlement added to to profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply for the entitlement here: https://developer.apple.com/contact/request/system-extension/.

For development teams, the form is only accessible for the Account Holder.

It currently looks like this:

[image: Entitlement application form]

If you check "USB Transport" you will also need to provide the relevant USB Vendor ID as an integer.

Comment: Here's some discouraging reading: https://mjtsai.com/blog/2019/07/05/requesting-entitlements/

Comment: FWIW, after two months of waiting, we finally got our entitlements for "USB Transport" for our vendor ID.